# Combine array from embedded document based on condition in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of student details like below:

```
  {
    "Student_id": 1,
    "StudentName": "ABC",
    "TestDetails": [{
            "SubtestName":"Reading", "TestSeq":1, "SubTestDetails":1, 
            "Scores":[{"ScoreType":"YY","ScoreValue":"100"},{"ScoreType":"XX","ScoreValue":"100"},
            {"ScoreType": "ZZ","ScoreValue":"100"}]}]
  ,
    "TestDetails": [{
            "SubtestName":"Writing", "TestSeq":1, "SubTestDetails":2, 
            "Scores":[{"ScoreType":"YY","ScoreValue":"200"},{"ScoreType":"XX","ScoreValue":"200"},
            {"ScoreType": "ZZ","ScoreValue":"200"}]}]
  ,
    "TestDetails": [{
            "SubtestName":"Listning", "TestSeq":2, "SubTestDetails":3, 
            "Scores":[{"ScoreType":"YY","ScoreValue":"300"},{"ScoreType":"XX","ScoreValue":"300"},
            {"ScoreType": "ZZ","ScoreValue":"300"}]}]
  ,
    "TestDetails": [{
            "SubtestName":"Speaking", "TestSeq":2, "SubTestDetails":4, 
            "Scores":[{"ScoreType":"YY","ScoreValue":"400"},{"ScoreType":"XX","ScoreValue":"400"},
            {"ScoreType": "ZZ","ScoreValue":"400"}]}]
  ,
    "TestDetails": [{
            "SubtestName":"Smartness", "TestSeq":3, "SubTestDetails":5, 
            "Scores":[{"ScoreType":"YY","ScoreValue":"500"},{"ScoreType":"XX","ScoreValue":"500"},
            {"ScoreType": "ZZ","ScoreValue":"500"}]}]
  },

  {
    "Student_id": 2,
    "StudentName": "XYZ",
    "TestDetails": [{
            "SubtestName":"Smartness", "TestSeq":1, "SubTestDetails":1, 
            "Scores":[{"ScoreType":"YY","ScoreValue":"100"},{"ScoreType":"XX","ScoreValue":"100"},
            {"ScoreType": "ZZ","ScoreValue":"100"}]}]
  ,
    "TestDetails": [{
            "SubtestName":"Writing", "TestSeq":1, "SubTestDetails":2, 
            "Scores":[{"ScoreType":"YY","ScoreValue":"200"},{"ScoreType":"XX","ScoreValue":"200"},
            {"ScoreType": "ZZ","ScoreValue":"200"}]}]
  ,
    "TestDetails": [{
            "SubtestName":"Listning", "TestSeq":2, "SubTestDetails":3, 
            "Scores":[{"ScoreType":"YY","ScoreValue":"300"},{"ScoreType":"XX","ScoreValue":"300"},
            {"ScoreType": "ZZ","ScoreValue":"300"}]}]
  ,
    "TestDetails": [{
            "SubtestName":"Speaking", "TestSeq":2, "SubTestDetails":4, 
            "Scores":[{"ScoreType":"YY","ScoreValue":"400"},{"ScoreType":"XX","ScoreValue":"400"},
            {"ScoreType": "ZZ","ScoreValue":"400"}]}]
  ,
    "TestDetails": [{
            "SubtestName":"Reading", "TestSeq":3, "SubTestDetails":5, 
            "Scores":[{"ScoreType":"YY","ScoreValue":"100"},{"ScoreType":"XX","ScoreValue":"100"},
            {"ScoreType": "ZZ","ScoreValue":"1000"}]}]
  }, 
  .
  .
  .
)
```

How can I create aggregate query to generate document like below:

```
{Student:1, "TestSeq" : 1, [{Subtest_name: Reading},{Subtest_name: Writing}]},
{Student:1,"TestSeq" :  2, [{Subtest_name: Listning},{Subtest_name: Speaking}]},
{Student:1, "TestSeq" : 3, [{Subtest_name: Smartness}]},
{Student:2, "TestSeq" : 1, [{Subtest_name: Smartness},{Subtest_name: Writing}]},
{Student:2, "TestSeq" : 2, [{Subtest_name: Listning},{Subtest_name: Speaking}]},
{Student:2, "TestSeq" : 3, [{Subtest_name: Reading}]},
{Student:3, "TestSeq" : 1, [{Subtest_name: Subtest1},{Subtest_name: Subtest2}]},
{Student:3, "TestSeq" : 2, [{Subtest_name: Subtest3},{Subtest_name: Subtest4}]},
{Student:3, "TestSeq" : 3, [{Subtest_name: Subtest5}]}
```

Logic is to combine/group Subtest name based on TestSeq values. For example Subtest names are combined for `TestSeq = 1`, for value 2 it's in 2nd row and 3 for last Subtest name for each student.

How can I implement that?

I have tried as below -

```
db.students.aggregate([ 
{$unwind: "$SubtestAttribs"},
{ $project: { student_name: 1, student_id : 1,
 print_ready : "$SubtestAttribs.TestSeq",
 Subtest_names :$SubtestAttribs.SubtestName" } } ])
```

But I am unable to form array based on condition. Above snippet giving data for each test seq. But how to combine two sub test name based on test seq?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? We're not really in the habbit of just writing your code for you.

Comment: db.students.aggregate([
 
{$unwind: "$SubtestAttribs"},


    { $project: {
        student_name: 1,
 student_id : 1,
 print_ready : "$SubtestAttribs.TestSeq",
        Subtest_names : "$SubtestAttribs.SubtestName"

        }
    }
   
]) I am unable to form array based on condition. above snippet giving data for each test seq. But how to combine two sub test name based on test seq?

Comment: Please edit your question to add that

Comment: I noticed also that your documents have the key `TestDetails` multiple times in a single document. Thats not really legal JSON since the keys are not unique... are you sure thats what your schema really looks like? I think its suppose to be a single key `TestDetails` that is an array of all the `TestDetails` you currently have in one.

Comment: Also, the output you want isn't legal JSON either: the array (ie `[{Subtest_name: Subtest5}]`) is missing a key.

Comment: SubTestDetails are unique in each TestDetails for each student. Also it can hold max value of 5.

Comment: plz consider output upto  student #2. Student#3 o/p is dummy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I'm making a couple assumptions because your question has some illegal JSON in it. Let me know if I guessed wrong. Also, I'm not on a computer with Mongo right now, so I might have some syntax issues.

```
db.students.aggregate([
{ $unwind: "$TestDetails" },
{
    $group:{
        _id: { Student: "$Student_id", TestSeq: "$TestDetails.TestSeq},
        Subtest_names: { $addToSet: "$TestDetails.Subtestname" }
    }
},
{
    $project:{
        Student: "$_id.Student",
        TestSeq: "$_id.TestSeq,
        Subtest_names: "$Subtest_names"
    }
}
])
```

Comment: Would give it to you since `$addToSet` is more appropriate here than `$push`, so +1 from me even though the OP's JSON is invalid :)

Comment: Appreciated your help. I will check and let you know.

Comment: I am getting below o/p -  { "_id" : { "Student" : 2, "TestSeq" : 3 }, "Subtest_names" : [ "Reading" ], "Student" : 2, "TestSeq" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "Student" : 1, "TestSeq" : 3 }, "Subtest_names" : [ "Smartness" ], "Student" : 1, "TestSeq" : 3 }  ..... Here I am getting one data for each student, while I need to find list of sub test names based on each test seq.

Comment: Change the line `Subtest_names: { $addToSet: "$TestDetails.Subtestname" }` to `"details": {
                "$addToSet": { "Subtest_name": "$TestDetails.SubtestName" }
            }` for it to work.

Comment: Thanks. It formatted the o/p. But how can I get multiple rows for same student depending on TestSeq? For exapml : {Student:1, "TestSeq" : 1, [{Subtest_name: Reading},{Subtest_name: Writing}]},
{Student:1,"TestSeq" :  2, [{Subtest_name: Listning},{Subtest_name: Speaking}]},
{Student:1, "TestSeq" : 3, [{Subtest_name: Smartness}]},
{Student:2, "TestSeq" : 1, [{Subtest_name: Smartness},{Subtest_name: Writing}]},
{Student:2, "TestSeq" : 2, [{Subtest_name: Listning},{Subtest_name: Speaking}]},
{Student:2, "TestSeq" : 3, [{Subtest_name: Reading}]},

Comment: Getting data for only last test sequence for each student. How to get multiple  data ?

Comment: It works for me. Thanks David Grinberg and chirdam for your help. There was some issue with my collection. After correction it works for me. Appreciated your help.